# "Setup is Starting..." screen stuck when Installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I am installing Windows 7 on my friends computer. I have booted form the installation disk, chosen the installation language, clicked OK, but this is where the problem starts:

The "Setup is starting..." screen pops up, and even after hours and hours of waiting, nothing happens. Should I try a new boot disk?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this impasse I believe in two solutions:

- Try with only one stick of memory.
- Use another install media.
- You can also try turning off unnecessary peripherals, those that could cause conflicts.

In latter case, use another drive CD/DVD.

Comment: Yeah its a laptop, so would I use a USB with Windows 7 on it?